Android App,Google Play Feature Delivery function had load So File Error
Caused by java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0 (Runtime.java:1082)
  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0 (Runtime.java:1003)
  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary (System.java:1661)

I will encounter this exception when saving. After the current PFD model is downloaded and installed, if the third-party SDK of so in base.apk is called, there will be an abnormal problem of loading so. I am very confused. Why does it affect the path access problem of so in base.apk after just downloading the PFD model?
And if there is a third-party SDK of so under my PFD model, then after my PFD model is just downloaded and installed, if I call the third-party SDK for so, there will be an abnormal problem of loading so path.
This is very troubling to me. I don’t know if anyone has encountered the same problem? How to deal with it?
I currently have no solution. I can only close the App and re-enter it to access the third-party SDK of so under the PFD model normally.
